# archiving in xcode 7.3.1

Tags: xcode, kivy

i am trying to get my app on testflight for testing. however when following the instruction on this video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tydk4Fc-tg&t=302s everything work up to trying to archive the app.
i get the below error and i'm not quite sure what to do. if you have any idea on how to solve this problem, please help. i'm using Xcode 7.3.1 and ivy 1.9.1.

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/nabi/Desktop/kivy-ios/break-ios/../build/lib'
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/nabi/Desktop/kivy-ios/dist/frameworks'
>
> ld: '/Users/nabi/Desktop/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libfreetype.a(ftsystem.o)'
>   does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled
>   (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the
>   vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)
>
> Ld
>   /Users/nabi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/break-bnyieydgxnbwarhabzewbmeqxnyr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/break/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/break.build/Release-iphoneos/break.build/Objects-normal/arm64/break
>   normal arm64
>       cd /Users/nabi/Desktop/kivy-ios/break-ios
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk
>   -L/Users/nabi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/break-bnyieydgxnbwarhabzewbmeqxnyr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/break/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
>   -L/Users/nabi/Desktop/kivy-ios/break-ios/../dist/lib -L/Users/nabi/Desktop/kivy-ios/break-ios/../build/lib -F/Users/nabi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/break-bnyieydgxnbwarhabzewbmeqxnyr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/break/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/nabi/Desktop/kivy-ios/dist/frameworks -filelist /Users/nabi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/break-bnyieydgxnbwarhabzewbmeqxnyr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/break/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/break.build/Release-iphoneos/break.build/Objects-normal/arm64/break.LinkFileList
>   -miphoneos-version-min=8.1 -fembed-bitcode -Xlinker -bitcode_verify -Xlinker -bitcode_hide_symbols -Xlinker -bitcode_symbol_map -Xlinker /Users/nabi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/break-bnyieydgxnbwarhabzewbmeqxnyr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/break/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
>   -all_load -fobjc-link-runtime -framework AudioToolbox -framework ImageIO -framework MessageUI -framework UIKit -framework OpenGLES
>   -framework CoreMotion -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreGraphics -framework Accelerate -framework QuartzCore -lc++ -lz
>   -lsqlite3 -lbz2 -lfreetype -lsdl2_mixer -lsdl2 -lsdl2_image -lffi -lkivy -lpython -lios -lsdl2_ttf -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/nabi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/break-bnyieydgxnbwarhabzewbmeqxnyr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/break/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/break.build/Release-iphoneos/break.build/Objects-normal/arm64/break_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/nabi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/break-bnyieydgxnbwarhabzewbmeqxnyr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/break/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/break.build/Release-iphoneos/break.build/Objects-normal/arm64/break
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/nabi/Desktop/kivy-ios/break-ios/../build/lib' ld: warning:
>   directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/nabi/Desktop/kivy-ios/dist/frameworks' ld:
>   '/Users/nabi/Desktop/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libfreetype.a(ftsystem.o)' does
>   not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode
>   setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or
>   disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64 clang: error:
>   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you clearly what to do. When you see the dialog that asks if you want to rebuild using bitcode, you must uncheck that option. If you are not even getting that far, use the build settings of your target to disable bitcode:

[image]

In that screen shot, you'd need to switch from Yes to No.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have read about the build settings at other places online but i'm not quite sure how to access it. i have been trying to access it for a while now but not sure how to find it. i'm new to programming and the Xcode environment. also there are no dialog asking if i want to rebuild using bit code

Comment: i just looked in the build setting and Enable Bitcode is already set to No. so i'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: i just succeeded in archiving. it seems like switching to yes and switching back to No solved the issue. thanks a lot for your help.